# converting php array into another format not working properly

Tags: php, json

I am new in json.The following is the result which I get from running a sql query in my php page.

```
ID      Name  Crs_ID  C_name  Tchr_name Tchr_ID classID

1052    Ahd   2      Arabic     Nahd     78      17
1052    Ahd   15     English    Beatr    28      17
1545    Ayh   7      Arabic    Mohamed   75      37
1545    Ayh   20     English    Andrea   126     37
```

I need this result in the form of following array like the following.

```
[{
{            
    "ID":1052,  
    "Name":'Ahd',
    "classid":17,

    "results":[
           { 
             "Crs_ID" : "7", 
             "C_name  ":"Arabic",
             "Tchr_name ":"Nahd",
             "Tchr_ID ":"78"         
           },
            { 
             "Crs_ID" : "20", 
             "C_name  ":"English",
             "Tchr_name ":"Beatr",
             "Tchr_ID ":"28"         
           }
             ]
  },
  {
     "ID":1545,  
    "Name":'Ayh',
    "classid":37,

    "results":[
           { 
             "Crs_ID" : "2", 
             "C_name  ":"Arabic",
             "Tchr_name ":"Mohamed",
             "Tchr_ID ":"75"         
           },
            { 
             "Crs_ID" : "15", 
             "C_name  ":"English",
             "Tchr_name ":"Andrea",
             "Tchr_ID ":"126"        
           }
             ]
   }
  }
  ]
```

I have used the following code to return the result.

```
//$results has the sql results
$temp_array = array();
foreach($results as $key=>$array_data)
            {

                if(!in_array($array_data[ID],$temp_array))
                {
                    $temp_array['ID']   = $array_data['ID'];
                    $temp_array['Name'] = $array_data['Name'];
                    $temp_array['classID']     = $array_data['classID'];
                    $temp_array['results_'.$array_data[ID]] = array();
                    $result_array  =array();
                }
                else
                {
                    array_push($temp_array['results_'.$array_data[ID]],'Crs_ID:'.$array_data['Crs_ID']);
                    array_push($temp_array['results_'.$array_data[ID]],'C_name:'.$array_data['C_name']);
                    array_push($temp_array['results_'.$array_data[ID]],'Tchr_name:'.$array_data['Tchr_name']);
                    array_push($temp_array['results_'.$array_data[ID]],'Tchr_ID:'.$array_data['Tchr_ID']);   
                    $result_array[] = $temp_array['results_'.$array_data[ID]];
                }
            }
            print_r(json_encode($result_array));
```

This is not giving me the correct format.

Comment: What's the correct format you are expecting?

Comment: The result, what you have given is an invalid JSON. It's not even a JSON.

Comment: A JSON cannot have `{{"stuff": "val"}, {"stuff": "val"}}` something like that.

Comment: I need the php array to be like this.Then I will convert it to json @PraveenKumar

Comment: I think you need to expect an array of arrays....

Comment: `json_encode` returns a string, so this `print_r(json_encode($result_array));` doesn't make sense. Use `echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` for more readable output. Still, the JSON result you want is invalid to begin with. `{{obj: 123}, {obj: 123}}` will always be `[{obj: 123}, {obj: 123}]`. Also `$array_data[ID]` is likely to issue a notice (unexpected `T_STRING` and something about PHP assuming `'ID'` (quoted stirng))

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Sorry I need the database result in the new format in PHP

Comment: @Techy: The format is ***invalid JSON***. You're representing an _array_, which is delimited by square brackets. Your question uses curly brackets for that array, which is not possible.

Comment: What are you going to do with the result? What's the end game? How are you going to use it later?

Comment: I need it to convert the new array into json and use it in mobAPI @MagnusEriksson

Comment: What's the format @Techy?

Comment: Ignore the square brackets,I need to make a php array like that without brackets.@EliasVanOotegem

Comment: @PraveenKumar ignore square bracket,I need to group the database result into a new multidimensional array where ID,name,class will be coming once,the c_id,t_name will be another array with keyname as results or something like that

Answer (score 1):

First, let's build your array.

```
$stmt = 'select ... from ...';

// Do your database logic here

$array = array();
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
    $array[] = $record;
}
```

PHP has the `json_encode()` function to convert arrays to json.

```
// Convert array to json
echo json_encode($array);
```

Converting json back to an array?

```
$array = json_decode($jsonString);
```

#### Resources

- [json_encode() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [json_decode() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I need to convert the database result into the above array format and then i need to convert it to json

Comment: He is actually already using `json_encode()` (the last row). His issue is that he expects the result to be like his example, which several people already pointed out, is not valid json.

Comment: This is not a valid answer as expected by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, your desired JSON is invalid. So here is a quick & dirty approach of *what I think* you want:

```
// Names of all fields that you want inside your "results" sub-array
$result_fields  = explode(",", "Crs_ID,C_name,Tchr_name,Tchr_ID");

// The array that has to be built 
$new_arr = array();

//  First foreach loops over all rows
foreach ($arr as $row) {

    // ID of the current student (this will be the key for your new array)
    $studentID = $row['ID'];

    // result-array for this row
    $result     = array();

    // Second foreach loops over all elements in the current row 
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

        // Check whether the current element belongs inside the result-array
        if (in_array($key, $result_fields)) {
            $result[$key]   = $value;

        // If not, add it to the main array directly
        } else {
            $new_arr[$studentID][$key]  = $value;
        }
    }

    // When done with all elements of this row, add the result-array to the main array
    $new_arr[$studentID]['results'][]   = $result;
}

// This reindexes the array, so that you have a zero- and sequentially-indexed array
$new_arr = array_values($new_arr);

// Encode to JSON 
$json = json_encode($new_arr);
```

I hope the comments make clear what is happening.

Fiddle: https://eval.in/671274